# PUSH NOTIFICATIONS: Change from GCM to Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android application where push notifications are implemented by GCM.

I need to change this. I need that with the new release (the app is already in the Store and people already use push with GCM) all the mechanism will be handle from Parse.

Can I simply delete everything concerning GCM and implement everything concerning PARSE and then upload the version of the application and be sure that everything will run the same?

Has anybody an idea if there will be conflicts with doing this? I'm thinking about devices that already have a GCM token for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it and see. I think when implementing Parse, the registration ID (unique to every app <--> device) will be generated again. I've written a [couple](http://codetheory.in/android-push-notifications-google-cloud-messaging/) of [articles](http://codetheory.in/android-push-notifications-parse-com/) on the topic which are not directly useful but can help in other ways.

Just make sure you follow [this](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) thoroughly.

Comment: I have implemented Parse Push according to their tutorials.Now I can send push notification to new devices which registered via new app.But now how can I send the push notification to my old user who doesn't have the new parse deviceId via same parse push console.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I had push notifications setup with Parse, and now I've added Gcm directly (for using with HelpShift) and I no longer receive parse notifications.

Comment: @ved  how u send notification to user have  u used client notification method ?

Comment: @Erum yes I have used my own Receiver and implemented getNotification() method to send my custom notification.